# Alpha blend watermark bmp in image bmp in c++

Tags: c++, bmp, alphablending

I have a task at school to add watermark bmp image into some other bmp image. The task is called alpha blending. I have to insert watermark at specific coordinates which user will set through program parameters on start, as well as alpha value for watermark blending. I am almost succeed, but I am getting small error. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BMP_SIGNATURE_0         0x42
#define BMP_SIGNATURE_1         0x4D
#define BMP_DEPTH               24
#define BMP_HDR_SIZE            24

int isValidBmp(unsigned char *header)
{
    if (header == NULL)
    return -1;

    if ((header[0] == BMP_SIGNATURE_0) && (header[1] == BMP_SIGNATURE_1))
    {
        if (header[28] != BMP_DEPTH)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

unsigned long getBmpWidth(unsigned char *header)
{
    unsigned long width;

    if (header == NULL)
        return 0;

    width = ((unsigned long)header[21] << 24) |
        ((unsigned long)header[20] << 16) |
        ((unsigned long)header[19] << 8) |
        (unsigned long)header[18];

    return width;
}

unsigned long getBmpHeight(unsigned char *header)
{
    unsigned long height;

    if (header == NULL)
        return 0;

    height = ((unsigned long)header[25] << 24) |
        ((unsigned long)header[24] << 16) |
        ((unsigned long)header[23] << 8) |
        (unsigned long)header[22];

    return height;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    FILE *fIn, *fOut, *fWaterMark;
    unsigned char *mIn, *mOut, *mWaterMark;
    unsigned long fsize, zsize;
    unsigned long fwidth, fheight, zwidth, zheight;;

    fIn = fopen("D:\\Downloads\\image.bmp", "rb");
    if (fIn == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(fIn, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fIn);

    mIn = (unsigned char *)malloc(fsize);
    fseek(fIn, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(mIn, sizeof(unsigned char), fsize, fIn);
    fclose(fIn);

    if (isValidBmp(mIn) == -1)
    {
        printf("ERROR!\n\n");
        free(mIn);
        return 1;
    }

    fwidth = getBmpWidth(mIn);
    fheight = getBmpHeight(mIn);

    if ((fwidth == 0) || (fheight == 0))
    {
        printf("ERROR!\n\n");
        free(mIn);
        return 1;
    }

    fWaterMark = fopen("D:\\Downloads\\watermark.bmp", "rb");
    if (fWaterMark == NULL)
    {
        free(mIn);
        printf("ERROR!\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek(fWaterMark, 0, SEEK_END);
    zsize = ftell(fWaterMark);

    mWaterMark = (unsigned char *)malloc(zsize);
    fseek(fWaterMark, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(mWaterMark, sizeof(unsigned char), zsize, fWaterMark);
    fclose(fWaterMark);

    if (isValidBmp(mWaterMark) == -1)
    {
        printf("ERROR!\n\n");
        free(mIn);
        free(mWaterMark);
        return 1;
    }

    zwidth = getBmpWidth(mWaterMark);
    zheight = getBmpHeight(mWaterMark);

    if ((zwidth == 0) || (zheight == 0))
    {
        printf("ERROR!\n\n");
        free(mIn);
        free(mWaterMark);
        return 1;
    }

    fOut = fopen("D:\\Downloads\\new_image.bmp", "wb");
    if (fOut == NULL)
    {
        free(mIn);
        free(mWaterMark);
        printf("ERROR!\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    mOut = (unsigned char *)malloc(fsize);
    fseek(fOut, 0, SEEK_SET);

    double alpha = 0.5;    

    memcpy(mOut, mIn, fsize);
    unsigned int index = BMP_HDR_SIZE;
    unsigned int x = 200, y = 200;
    for (unsigned int i = BMP_HDR_SIZE + x*y; i < x*y + zsize; i++)
    {
        unsigned char v = ((1 - alpha) * mIn[i]) + mWaterMark[index++];
        mOut[i] = v;
    }
    fwrite(mOut, sizeof(unsigned char), fsize, fOut);

    free(mIn);
    free(mOut);
    fclose(fOut);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample BMP image:

[image: oh look it is actually a BMP!]

Comment: Do you want to tell us the small error you're getting or is it a secret?

Comment: Why did you tag this as C++ when you're using malloc?  Why not "mIn = new unsigned char[fsize];" and "delete [] mIn" instead of free?

Comment: Hi @Blastfurnace here is the "small error":
<img src=\"http://expert.its.me/temporary/new_image.bmp\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your loop over a 2-dimensional array of bitmap points.  Change your loop to be a double loop.  Also:

- You are not using the correct offset for the pixel range.
- You need to multiply width times 3 to copy all 3 component colors of a pixels
- You should use the rounded off row length to make sure you cover any padding.
- Your y is offset from the bottom of the picture, use trueY to have your offset from the top.
- It helps to have a different error text for each error to know which error is triggering; I've left it as an exercise to come up with more helpful text.
- I voted you up because I think this is an interesting question; I had to dig into the Wikipedia page for BMP files to come up with the final answer.
- You were only using half-alpha on the source, but to reproduce that image you shared in your comments, you need to take half-alpha for both the image and the watermark.

Note also to reproduce the image you shared in the comments, x must be 125 and y must be 100.  All that said, this code looks like it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>

#define BMP_SIGNATURE_0         0x42
#define BMP_SIGNATURE_1         0x4D
#define BMP_DEPTH               24
#define BMP_HDR_SIZE            24

int isValidBmp(unsigned char *header)
{
    if (header == NULL)
        return -1;

    if ((header[0] == BMP_SIGNATURE_0) && (header[1] == BMP_SIGNATURE_1))
        {
            if (header[28] != BMP_DEPTH)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    else
        return -1;
}

unsigned long getBmpWidth(unsigned char *header)
{
    unsigned long width;

    if (header == NULL)
        return 0;

    width = ((unsigned long)header[21] << 24) |
        ((unsigned long)header[20] << 16) |
        ((unsigned long)header[19] << 8) |
        (unsigned long)header[18];

    return width;
}

unsigned long getBmpHeight(unsigned char *header)
{
    unsigned long height;

    if (header == NULL)
        return 0;

    height = ((unsigned long)header[25] << 24) |
        ((unsigned long)header[24] << 16) |
        ((unsigned long)header[23] << 8) |
        (unsigned long)header[22];

    return height;
}

unsigned long getPixelOffset(unsigned char *header)
{
    unsigned long offset;

    if (header == NULL)
        return 0;

    offset = ((unsigned long)header[13] << 24) |
        ((unsigned long)header[12] << 16) |
        ((unsigned long)header[11] << 8) |
        (unsigned long)header[10];

    return offset;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    FILE *fIn, *fOut, *fWaterMark;
    unsigned char *mIn, *mOut, *mWaterMark;
    unsigned long fsize, zsize;
    unsigned long fwidth, fheight, zwidth, zheight;
    unsigned long foffset, frow, zoffset, zrow;

    fIn = fopen("srcso.bmp", "rb");
    if (fIn == NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR 1!\n\n");
            return 1;
        }

    fseek(fIn, 0, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fIn);

    mIn = (unsigned char *)malloc(fsize);
    fseek(fIn, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(mIn, sizeof(unsigned char), fsize, fIn);
    fclose(fIn);

    if (isValidBmp(mIn) == -1)
        {
            printf("ERROR 2!\n\n");
            free(mIn);
            return 1;
        }

    fwidth = getBmpWidth(mIn);
    fheight = getBmpHeight(mIn);
    foffset = getPixelOffset(mIn);
    frow = (BMP_DEPTH * fwidth + 31) / 32 * 4;

    if ((fwidth == 0) || (fheight == 0))
        {
            printf("ERROR 3!\n\n");
            free(mIn);
            return 1;
        }

    fWaterMark = fopen("wmso.bmp", "rb");
    if (fWaterMark == NULL)
        {
            free(mIn);
            printf("ERROR 4!\n\n");
            return 1;
        }

    fseek(fWaterMark, 0, SEEK_END);
    zsize = ftell(fWaterMark);

    mWaterMark = (unsigned char *)malloc(zsize);
    fseek(fWaterMark, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(mWaterMark, sizeof(unsigned char), zsize, fWaterMark);
    fclose(fWaterMark);

    if (isValidBmp(mWaterMark) == -1)
        {
            printf("ERROR 5!\n\n");
            free(mIn);
            free(mWaterMark);
            return 1;
        }

    zwidth = getBmpWidth(mWaterMark);
    zheight = getBmpHeight(mWaterMark);
    zoffset = getPixelOffset(mWaterMark);
    zrow = (BMP_DEPTH * zwidth + 31) / 32 * 4;

    if ((zwidth == 0) || (zheight == 0))
        {
            printf("ERROR 6!\n\n");
            free(mIn);
            free(mWaterMark);
            return 1;
        }

    fOut = fopen("new_image.bmp", "wb");
    if (fOut == NULL)
        {
            free(mIn);
            free(mWaterMark);
            printf("ERROR 7!\n\n");
            return 1;
        }

    mOut = (unsigned char *)malloc(fsize);
    fseek(fOut, 0, SEEK_SET);

    double alpha = 0.5;    

    std::copy(mIn, mIn + fsize, mOut);
    ::free(mIn);
    mIn = 0;
    unsigned int index = BMP_HDR_SIZE;
    unsigned int x = 200, y = 200;
    unsigned int trueY = fheight - y - zheight;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < zheight; ++j) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < zwidth*3; ++i) {
            const size_t offset = foffset + (j + trueY) * frow + i + x*3;
            unsigned char * const offOut = mOut + offset; 
            unsigned char * const offWM = mWaterMark + zoffset + j * zrow + i;
            *offOut *= 1 - alpha;
            *offWM *= 1 - alpha;
            if ((unsigned int)*offOut + (unsigned int)*offWM < 265)
                *offOut += *offWM;
            else
                *offOut = 255;
        }
    }
    fwrite(mOut, sizeof(unsigned char), fsize, fOut);
    fclose(fOut);

    ::free(mWaterMark);
    ::free(mOut);

    return 0;
}
```

Note, the if you have an alpha less than .5, you will get strange color artifacts because the algorithm could ping say red but leave blue and green normal making the blue and green seem brighter than they should be.  Technically, when the else case happens for the pixel setting, it should really affect the other two pixels by adding more to them to compensate for this effect.

Comment: I am still getting a wrong result. Here is my image:
<img src=\"http://expert.its.me/temporary/image.bmp\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\" />
Here is the watermark:
<img src=\"http://expert.its.me/temporary/watermark.bmp\" width=\"75\" height=\"75\" />
Here is the result from the solution suggested by the @TimeHorse:
<img src=\"http://expert.its.me/temporary/new_image.bmp\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\" />
While the correct result should be:
<img src=\"http://expert.its.me/temporary/new_img.bmp\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\" />
Please help!

Comment: I forget whether bmps store rows of columns (x rows, layered upon y columns) or columns of rows.  I'm going to examine your results and will let you know when I have it modified but I'm sure it's just a question of row vs. column.

Comment: Excellent news. I'll wait. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I jost noticed, though this doesn't fix it, that since mOut already contains a copy of mIn, we don't need mIn once it's copied.  So I'll change the code above.

Comment: I had to move a lot of snow but I'm getting closer.  It turns out you're not using the correct pixel offset either.  But it's still not quite right.  I'm still investigating.

Comment: There you are my friend, I've fixed your code and it works exactly as per your request.  Please note all the bullet points because these outline what your code was missing.  Also, the reason I mention the upvote is because my last question was unfairly downvoted and I know how that feels when I see a legitimate question.  Good luck @expert.its.me and hope this helps!

Comment: Excellent work @TimeHorse - the job is done! You earn an upvote (or few) my friend. I have reputation 6, so the system won't allow me to set an upvote. If there is a possibility for me to do something - please let me know. I'll be glad to help - the same way you did for me. Thank you so much. One more thing: as soon as I get reputation more than 15, rest assure that I'll provide an upvote. Best regards..

Comment: It was an interesting problem; glad to help!

Comment: @expert.its.me And don't forget to click the grey checkmark under the answer voting to say this is the officially working answer you were looking for.  Take care.

Comment: Sure thing @TimeHorse - you've earned it. Regards!